# Visual Web Part for 4 Level Top Navigation

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I want to create a visual web part for 4 level top navigation,my requirement is mentioned on the following link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b3b63bc6-8d2b-4781-bdd7-579cc52e5754/visual-web-part-for-4-level-top-navigation?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: You want us to code for you ?

Comment: Do we get the pay as well?

Comment: I want if any one have worked on the binding like this so suggest me i would code myself

Answer (score 0):

1).If you can avoid 4 list you mentioned in your question,

I've used like this.....
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768564/How-To-Create-Multi-Level-Menu-Dynamically-Using-C

Instead of Database table create SharePoint list ........

2) using 4 lists .. Make a some lookup column in 2nd list to 1st list

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     list1()
     list2()
     list3()
     list4()
    }



    private void list1()
    {
      //read from list and dynamically bind it to asp.net control panel or div
    }
    private void list2()
    {
      //read from list
    }
```